# Manipulating a list into an associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following variable $toEmails which contains 3 email address in it separated by a semicolon. What I would like to do is put each of those email addresses into an array and also add another two bits of information in the array, like the 'Name' and 'to' variables.

Reading online I need to use the php explode command to split it in an array, but then I'm getting a little lost on how to inject extra data to the array. I think I should be usingthe array_push command to insert the other data in?

This is the data I have

```
$toEmails = "a@hotmail.com;b@yahoo.com;c@gmail.com";
$myName = "myName";
```

This is the output I desire

```
        array(
            'email' => 'a@hotmail.com',
            'name' => 'myName',
            'type' => 'to'
        ),
        array(
            'email' => 'b@yahoo.com',
            'name' => 'myName',
            'type' => 'to'
        ),
        array(
            'email' => 'c@gmail.com',
            'name' => 'myName',
            'type' => 'to'
        )
```

$arremails = explode(";", $toEmails);

Comment: and what is the problem? Explode string, then you get an array of emails, loop this array and make new array's in loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new array and copy the "exploded" emails.

```
$toEmails = "a@hotmail.com;b@yahoo.com;c@gmail.com";
$myName = "myName";

$arremails = explode(";", $toEmails);
$newArray = [];

foreach($arremails as $email) {
    $newArray[] = [
        'email' => $email,
        'name' => $myName,
        'type' => 'to'
    ];
}
```

Or update the value in the array using a referenced `foreach` loop.

```
$toEmails = "a@hotmail.com;b@yahoo.com;c@gmail.com";
$myName = "myName";

$arremails = explode(";", $toEmails);
$newArray = [];

foreach($arremails as &$email) {
    $email = [
        'email' => $email,
        'name' => $myName,
        'type' => 'to'
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest solution is this one:

```
$toEmails = "a@hotmail.com;b@yahoo.com;c@gmail.com";
$myName = "myName";
$arremails = [];

foreach(explode(';', $toEmails) as $email) {
    $arremails[] = [
        'email' => $email,
        'name' => $myName,
        'type' => 'to'
    ];
}
print_r($arremails);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
$toEmails = "a@hotmail.com;b@yahoo.com;c@gmail.com";
$myName = "myName";

$emails = explode(';', $toEmails);
$output = array_map(
    function ($email) use ($myName) {
        return [
            'email' => $email,
            'name' => $myName,
            'type' => 'to',
        ];
    },
    $emails
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function array_map() (http://php.net/array_map).

```
$toEmails = "a@hotmail.com;b@yahoo.com;c@gmail.com";
$myName = "myName";

$result = array_map(function ($element) use ($myName) {
    return array('email' => $element, 'name' => $myName, 'type' => 'to');   
}, explode(';', $toEmails));

print_r($result);
```

From PHP 5.4, you can use [] instead of array().